# View sqlite database for my mac application?

Tags: macos, core-data, xcode7

I am new to mac application development, I have written a mac OSX application using Coredata in Xcode, I want to view the contents of the database, as we do in iOS simulator but have no idea to view mac application DB files. I  have installed SQLite Manager but where by default XCode put the mac application SQLite files. I am unable to access.

Answer (score 0):

if your app is sandboxed `~/Library/Containers/com.yourcompany.yourAppName/` is where you should look. If your app is not sandboxed then it's somewhere in `~/Library/Application Support/`.

Comment: my app is not sandboxed and found a folder with same name as my app but no sqlite file was there (in ~/Library/Application Support/.)